# Javascript: Compare 2 array of objects and remove elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 array objects with user purchase counts. I am trying to compare the 2 arrays to see which purchased product has a larger count of purchases. If the `newUser` has a larger count then the `oldUser` the oldUsers object will be removed and vice versa.

eg shoes count = 2 for `newUser` and shoes count = 4.5 for `oldUser` therefore it gets removed from the newUser array as shown in `newUserOutput`

**What I have**

I can currently get the intersection to compare which purchased product is in each array but I don't know how to remove the intersection with a greater count or to output two separate arrays

**What I have tried:**

```
    const newUser = [
    { count: 2, purchased: "shoes"}, // smaller then oldUser
    { count: 2, purchased: "iphone"},
    { count: 2, purchased: "cup"},// greater then oldUser
    { count: 1, purchased: "charger"},// smaller then oldUser
    { count: 1, purchased: "plant"}, 

]
const oldUser = [
    { count: 4.5, purchased: "shoes"},// greater then newUser
    { count: 3.5, purchased: "charger"},// greater then newUser
    { count: 3.5, purchased: "macbook"},
    { count: 1, purchased: "cup"}, // smaller then newUser
]

const handleIntersection = () =>{
    const results = newUser.filter(({ purchased: id1 }) => !oldUser.some(({ purchased: id2 }) => id2 === id1));
    console.log(results)
    // I don't know how to get the two separe array outputs. 
    //I have tried to find the intersection of each purchased item
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
const newUserOutput = [
    { count: 2, purchased: "iphone"},
    { count: 2, purchased: "cup"},
    { count: 1, purchased: "plant"},
]

const oldUserOutput = [
    { count: 4.5, purchased: "shoes"},
    { count: 3.5, purchased: "charger"},
    { count: 3.5, purchased: "macbook"},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect greater purchases and generate a new result set with only the gretest values.

```js
const
    newUser = [{ count: 2, purchased: "shoes" }, { count: 2, purchased: "iphone" }, { count: 2, purchased: "cup" }, { count: 1, purchased: "charger" }, { count: 1, purchased: "plant" }],
    oldUser = [{ count: 4.5, purchased: "shoes" }, { count: 3.5, purchased: "charger" }, { count: 3.5, purchased: "macbook" }, { count: 1, purchased: "cup" }],
    result = {},
    greaters = Object.entries({ newUser, oldUser }).reduce((r, [k, a]) => {
        a.forEach(o => {
            if (!r[o.purchased] || r[o.purchased].o.count < o.count) r[o.purchased] = { k, o };
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

Object.values(greaters).forEach(({ k, o }) => (result[k] ??= []).push(o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `newUserOutput` and filter the `newUserOutput` elements from oldUser.

```js
   const newUser = [
    { count: 2, purchased: "shoes"}, // smaller then oldUser
    { count: 2, purchased: "iphone"},
    { count: 2, purchased: "cup"},// greater then oldUser
    { count: 1, purchased: "charger"},// smaller then oldUser
    { count: 1, purchased: "plant"}, 

]
const oldUser = [
    { count: 4.5, purchased: "shoes"},// greater then newUser
    { count: 3.5, purchased: "charger"},// greater then newUser
    { count: 3.5, purchased: "macbook"},
    { count: 1, purchased: "cup"}, // smaller then newUser
]


const newUserUpdated =  newUser.filter((item) =>{
    const found =  oldUser.find((a) => a.purchased === item.purchased);
    return found ? found.count < item.count : true;
} );


const oldUserUpdated = oldUser.filter((item) =>{
    const found =  newUserUpdated.find((a) => a.purchased === item.purchased);
    return found ? false : true;
} )

console.log({newUserUpdated, oldUserUpdated})
```